# Response body in Postman is not in human-readable way, with proper indentation and line breaks

Tags: postman

my response body (Pretty, JSON format) in Postman is not in human-readable way, with proper indentation and line breaks, it is such as text area. All the dates is in one line as a text. Please how  can beautify the response body? Thanks.

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTVBj.png)

Comment: what is your one line data? you needs to show in your question and how to get that data, Screen capture of header, input body, URL and verb (GET, POST) will help to get an answer for your question.

Comment: In my Postman there are tabs for viewing the response, including "Preview" and "Pretty" tabs.  Do you not have those?  Please clarify the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I shared the prtsc capture also.

Comment: What are the response headers?

Comment: Should be make pretty JSON by Postman , I think your response body needs a check correct JSON. Can you try to check in [here](https://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: @David Thanks for help, I also send a prtsc of the responce header.

Comment: @BenchVue Yes, I tried, and JSON validate correct.

Comment: Can you share your json by text after hide private information I can mocking server and try to fix by client by Postman

Comment: @BenchVue {"rober":"15","timpe":7,"isFirstHalf":false,"place":"Ž","substitude":"K","lastChangeInfo":"A","approver":"B","createdAt":"2024-03-26","balInfo":null,"isSystRec":false,"canBeDenied":true,"from":"2024-04-22T15:30:06","to":"2024-04-22T15:40:06","periodDescription":"20. 04. 2024","note":"S"}

Comment: @IrynaRybovich, Thanks I answered with your JSON file can you try mocking the server and calling Postman and cURL , if you get it. Try your real endpoint API.

Comment: What version of Postman is this? Do you get a correctly formatted response if you do a GET to https://postman-echo.com/get ?

Comment: @Danny Dainton Version 10.24.7-240320-0056.  When I try GET request to postman-echo.com/get , all JSON response are now in correct way. Maybe it was a solution :) Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this mock-server test?

##### Mocking Server

save as `server.js`

```js
const express = require("express")
const cors = require("cors")

const app = express()
app.use(cors())

app.get("/api/data", async (req, res) => {
    data = {"rober":"15","timpe":7,"isFirstHalf":false,"place":"Ž","substitude":"K","lastChangeInfo":"A","approver":"B","createdAt":"2024-03-26","balInfo":null,"isSystRec":false,"canBeDenied":true,"from":"2024-04-22T15:30:06","to":"2024-04-22T15:40:06","periodDescription":"20. 04. 2024","note":"S"}
    res.json(data)
})

app.get("/api/long-data", async (req, res) => {
    data = {"attributes": [{"name": "username", "displayName": "${username}", "validations": {"length": {"min": 3, "max": 255}, "username-prohibited-characters": {}, "up-username-not-idn-homograph": {}}, "permissions": {"view": ["admin", "user"], "edit": ["admin", "user"]}, "multivalued": false}, {"name": "email", "displayName": "${email}", "validations": {"email": {}, "length": {"max": 255}}, "required": {"roles": ["user"]}, "permissions": {"view": ["admin", "user"], "edit": ["admin", "user"]}, "multivalued": false}, {"name": "firstName", "displayName": "${firstName}", "validations": {"length": {"max": 255}, "person-name-prohibited-characters": {}}, "required": {"roles": ["user"]}, "permissions": {"view": ["admin", "user"], "edit": ["admin", "user"]}, "multivalued": false}, {"name": "lastName", "displayName": "${lastName}", "validations": {"length": {"max": 255}, "person-name-prohibited-characters": {}}, "required": {"roles": ["user"]}, "permissions": {"view": ["admin", "user"], "edit": ["admin", "user"]}, "multivalued": false}, {"name": "custom", "displayName": "${custom}", "validations": {"length": {"max": 255}}, "annotations": {}, "permissions": {"view": ["admin"], "edit": ["admin", "user"]}, "multivalued": false}], "groups": [{"name": "user-metadata", "displayHeader": "User metadata", "displayDescription": "Attributes, which refer to user metadata"}]}
    res.json(data)
})

const port = 3000
app.listen(port, () => { console.log(`Listening on : ${port}`) })
```

##### Install node.js

if not yet install `node.js` in your PC.

```
https://nodejs.org/en/download
```

##### Install dependencies

```
npm install express cors
```

##### Run it

```
node server.js
```

[image]

##### Call it by Postman

```
GET http://localhost:3000/api/data
```

[image]

long JSON data

```
GET http://localhost:3000/api/long-data
```

[image]

##### call by cURL

Not pretty option

```
curl --request GET \
  --silent \
  --url 'http://localhost:3000/api/data' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'
```

[image]

Pretty option
Install json first

```
npm install -g json
```

```
curl --request GET \
  --silent \
  --url 'http://localhost:3000/api/data' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' | json
```

[image]

So can you try this cURL for your real API?